# Suspend execution of next step until current step is completed in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, umbraco7

I have implemented functionality in Angular js using Umbraco entiryResource, Here is my code sample.

```
entityResource.getById(value, 'Member')
 .then(function (ent) {
                        value = ent.name;                                          
                    });
return value;
```

The problem is "return value;" statement executes before the line inside ".then()". I just want to wait the execution to complete the ".then()" and then move to next step.

How to achieve this?

Comment: You can't. Return the whole promise instead and use another then() to do what is needed

Comment: JavaScript does non-blocking asynchronous I/O. It does not wait. If you want a language that waits, look elsewhere.